# How to find in which tables a column from another table is used either as a foreign key column or normal column in SQL Server

Tags: sql-server, foreign-keys

I wanted to know all the tables where the column from another table is used as a foreign key or normal key.

For example: list all the tables where the `tran_id` column from the table `Transactions` is used. `tran_id` can either be a foreign key or just a normal column.

I tried using the following query but it returns tables with foreign key constraints only.

```
SELECT 
    OBJECT_NAME(f.parent_object_id) TableName,
    COL_NAME(fc.parent_object_id, fc.parent_column_id) ColName
FROM 
    sys.foreign_keys AS f
INNER JOIN 
    sys.foreign_key_columns AS fc ON f.OBJECT_ID = fc.constraint_object_id
INNER JOIN 
    sys.tables t ON t.OBJECT_ID = fc.referenced_object_id
WHERE 
    OBJECT_NAME (f.referenced_object_id) = 'YourTableName'
```

Any help? Thanks in advance.

Comment: What do you mean by normal column (as opposed to foreign key)?

Comment: The column "tran_id" from the table "Transactions" is present in another table "Table2" but there is no foreign key relationship between both these tables/columns.

Comment: If you haven't told SQL Server these columns are related by declaring a foreign key how do you expect it to know? Do you want all tables that have a column with that name?

Answer (score 0):

You could use a query like this:

```
select   tab.name, col.name
from    sys.columns col
inner join sys.tables tab
on col.object_id = tab.object_id
WHERE col.name = 'tran_id'
```

You would then have to manually find the relevant implicit FKs.

Is RI enforced partly by the logic tier and not always by the database server?